# bad config line 1 .gitconfig

Tags: git, macos, terminal

Obligatory mention that I am new to git

I cannot get anything to work in my macOS terminal in regards to git and everything I do returns the same error

I have tried to find my `.git/config` file to delete it because that's what others have suggested and nothing else seems to work.

I have tried several commands that others have answered in the questions similar to mine, including `git config --global --edit`, `git config --list --show-origin`, and restating my `user.name` and `user.email`.

Everything that I attempt returns the

```
error: "fatal: bad config line 1 in file /Users/myName/.gitconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file from your terminal.

```
vi ~/.gitconfig
```

The file is located in your home directory.
In case you have multiple config files use the same command as you mentioned in your question:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

to track all your config files

If you still have problems, copy the content of your file (backup) delete it and  create a new one

```
# bckup old file
mv ~/.gitignore ~/.gitignore.old

# Create new file 
touch ~/.gitignore

# Set the username /email
git config --global user.name <....>
git config --global user.email<....>
```